# A man with a rifle shoots bullets at a speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, momentum, conservation-laws, projectile

[image: enter link description here]

Hello all
So I was doing this question.

I had a doubt that, initially as both the (man and rifle ) system and the bullet were at rest we put 0 instead of m1u1 + m2u2 in equation of conservation of momentum and hence get the speed of the system as 0.08 m/s after the first shot.

But , after the first shot we can't do the same for the subsequent shots as both the  system and the bullet will have some velocity ( they both will have the same velocity in the same direction. ) and hence for subsequent shots the velocities gained by system would be different than 0.08 m/s. Then how can we just give the answer as 10 × (the velocity gained in the first shot.) .
ie:  0.8 m/s

This was the answer given in the book.

Comment: Imagine the momentum of the bullets at the end of the firing. Shouldn't this value be equal to the momentum of the man?

Comment: Yeah but thats where the problem starts , in the first firing the system gains a velocity of .08 m/s . now when the second firing takes place the actual velocity of second bullet => $v_{bullet} = v_{bullet/system} + v_{system} $ which in this case would be 800+(-.08)= 799.2m/s. I know this is a negligible change but still a change is a change.

Comment: Somebody should write to the publishers of that text book and tell them that "smooth" does not mean _frictionless_. The man could be standing, for example, on a plate of float glass. That would be an extremely smooth surface, but clean, rubber-soled shoes would be quite grippy on clean glass.

Comment: @SolomonSlow It could also just mean "able to be differentiated".  I personally don't see it as a big deal though.  I think if taught properly, it can even be a learning opportunity.  Teaching students to use somewhat unclear information to make assumptions about the problem can be useful; as long as they also have to state those assumptions and why.  Being clear is generally better; but there are some benefits to having students interpret assumptions themselves.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "Smooth" has long been a stand-in for "frictionless" in physics texts.

Answer (score 1):

We can do the same for each subsequent shot, because the momentum change with each subsequent shot is the same as the momentum change with the first shot.  Look at the impact = momentum relationship.

$F\ \Delta t =m\ \Delta v$

Each shot produces the same $F\ \Delta t$ and therefore produces the same momentum change in the man and his muzzle.

Another way to look at it is that the bullet exits with the same muzzle velocity with each shot, so the fact that the muzzle is moving backwards after the first shot is irrelevant.  Even though the bullet moves less than 800 m/s with respect to the ground after the first shot, it started with a negative velocity, so that its change in velocity and therefore, its momentum change is the same as it was with the first shot.  So it imparts the same momentum change in the man and his muzzle as did the first shot.

Since each shot produces the same momentum change in the man as the first shot, it is correct to multiply the effect of the first shot by the total number of shots.

Comment: $F \Delta t = m \Delta v$ to me shows that you can't just add them.  If $F \Delta t$ were the same each time, why wouldn't you have to consider that although you get the same $\Delta v$; that's in the man's reference frame, which changes velocity each time.  So you would need to account for that when determining the absolute change in velocity relative to a stationary frame.

Comment: $F$ is absolute so the change in velocity is also.

Comment: We're actually given the $m \Delta v$ _relative to the gun_ for each shot in this question.  It doesn't seem clear to me why you can ignore that.  If you calculated this in the mans frame of reference for each step, you would get a different answer.

Comment: Each bullet has the same absolute $\Delta p$. The man,therefore, must have the same absolute $\Delta p$ in the opposite direction.  The point is that an applied force changes the momentum absolutely, and that CHANGE does not depend on the previous momentum the object had prior to the applied force.

Comment: How do you conclude it has that momentum in the _absolute_ frame?  We know the muzzle velocity; which is the difference in velocity between the bullet and the gun.  Therefore that tells us the momentum change in the _shooters_ reference frame is the same.  The shooters reference frame changes from the "absolute" one as he keeps gaining velocity with each shot.

Comment: Say a few shots have been fired and the man's velocity is -10. A new bullet leaves him at $v=800$ in his reference frame.  In the ground frame the bullet has a velocity of 790. The ground frame change in velocity is $790-(-10)=800$, the same as in the man frame.  Therefore each shot produces the same $\Delta p$ absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Intrigued by @Bill Watts answer I decided to do this answer step by step and found out that Bill was indeed right. 
But I also observed that we all were also right but the thing was that we weren't actually calculating the values on pen and paper and hence believed that multiplying the initial velocity by 10 would be wrong.
Anyway here is the solution

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Loving the notepaper!

Comment: In a good way or a bad way ?

Comment: In a good way, definitely!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine only one bullet is being fired. If (after the firing) the velocity of this bullet is $v_b$ and the velocity of the system (man + remaining bullets) is $v_s$, then we apply momentum conservation as follows:

$m_Sv_s + m_bv_b = 0$ or $\frac{v_s}{v_b} = -\frac{m_b}{m_s} $

Therefore, after firing one shot, the velocities of the man and the bullet, will in general not be the same.

We can iterate this for 10 bullets, by changing our 'system' variables for each shot fired.

Alternatively we need only apply momentum conservation once if we look at the system before the first shot and after the last shot since all the bullets are fired independently and the momentum of the man + rifle + ten bullets does not change (since no forces act on this larger system as a whole)

Therefore if $m_r$ and $v_r$ denote the mass and the velocity of the man + rifle and $v_b$ and $m_b$ represent the velocity and mass of each bullet (velocity of a bullet does not change once fired) the total momentum of this system will be

$m_rv_r + 10m_bv_b = 0$

Since we know the total mass and the mass of each bullet, we can solve for $v_r$ here which is the required answer.

The reason this can be done directly, is because through the firing of the 10 shots, no external force acts on the bullets + rifle + man system, so its total linear momentum is what it was before the first shot is fired, which is zero.

EDIT: Okay so if muzzle velocity here refers to the velocity of the bullet wrt the muzzle alone, then momentum conservation must be applied ten times separately. We can do this from the ground frame by calculating the velocity of each bullet wrt to the ground since we know the muzzle velocity and the velocity of the gun after each shot. In the ground state, any force on the rifle due to the bullet (and vice versa) will still be internal forces as long as we re calculate the right velocities after each shot.

Comment: The velocity of a bullet doesn't change once fired; but each bullet is not fired at the same velocity relative to a stationary observer (assuming "muzzle velocity" is the velocity of the bullet relative to the muzzle).  As the gun gains backwards momentum; $v_b$ would change accordingly in the absolute frame, so $10 m_b v_b$ doesn't work since each bullet has a different $v_b$.

Comment: Yeah exactly @Jmac thats what I was trying to say

Comment: unless I overlooked it, everyone seems to be missing that each bullet weighs 10 grams, so the next bullet is accelerating 10 grams less than the previous

Comment: So I worked the problem taking the muzzle velocity to mean the velocity with which the bullet leaves wrt the ground. For when that is not the case, I have made an edit.

Comment: @Adrian Howard the way the question is written I don't think so we have go in such detail

Comment: But yeah the most accurate result would obviously be attained taking your statement into account @Adrian Howard

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with basic what question actually want since man has mass of 100kg (including gun mass) ,the question is all about momentum conservation since no impulsive force is present momentum relationship.

F Δt=0 so initial momentum =final momentum so lets start when bullet one is fired initial momentum was zero so the final momentum should also.equate to zero 1000 multiply x (x:velocity of man experience in opposite direction of bullet travel )=800 multiply 0.01 so you get the velocity x now for firing the shot 2 man has already momentum of mx so equate and you will yourself able to analyze the pattern please comment if you not able to solve for part b momentum relationship.

F Δt=10F delta t=10 initial.momentum of man was zero final you calculate in part 1